# r: Reading a dataset where each observation is split into 2 lines?

Tags: r, dataset, newline

I'm trying to read a space-delimited file where each observation is broken halfway by a newline. Is there a way to make read.table or fread scan for values until the entire row is full?

Header and first 2 rows of dataset looks like this:

```
   tsales sales margin nown nfull npart naux hoursw hourspw inv1 inv2 ssize start
       750000   4411.765         41          1          1          1     1.5357
           76   16.75596   17166.67   27177.04        170         41
      1926395   4280.878         39          2          2          3     1.5357
          192   22.49376   17166.67   27177.04        450         39
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each row of final data is split into perfectly 2 lines in your input you can try this -

```r
#read file
txt <- readLines("test.txt")

#extract header and remove it from data
df_header <- strsplit(txt[1], split=" ")[[1]]
txt <- txt[-1]

#merge every 2 subseqeunt lines into one to form a row of final dataframe
idx <- seq(1, length(txt), by=2)
txt[idx] <- paste(txt[idx], txt[idx+1])
txt <- txt[-(idx+1)]

#final data
df <- read.table(text=txt, col.names=df_header)
```

**Output is:**

```
   tsales    sales margin nown nfull npart   naux hoursw  hourspw     inv1     inv2 ssize start
1  750000 4411.765     41    1     1     1 1.5357     76 16.75596 17166.67 27177.04   170    41
2 1926395 4280.878     39    2     2     3 1.5357    192 22.49376 17166.67 27177.04   450    39
```

**Sample data:** `test.txt` contains

```
tsales sales margin nown nfull npart naux hoursw hourspw inv1 inv2 ssize start
750000   4411.765         41          1          1          1     1.5357
76   16.75596   17166.67   27177.04        170         41
1926395   4280.878         39          2          2          3     1.5357
192   22.49376   17166.67   27177.04        450         39
```

Comment: Glad that it helped!

Answer (score 1):

I'm reading your sample Data, It looks like this...

```
   tsales      sales   margin     nown nfull npart   naux hoursw hourspw inv1 inv2 ssize start
1  750000 4411.76500    41.00     1.00     1     1 1.5357     NA      NA   NA   NA    NA    NA
2      76   16.75596 17166.67 27177.04   170    41     NA     NA      NA   NA   NA    NA    NA
3 1926395 4280.87800    39.00     2.00     2     3 1.5357     NA      NA   NA   NA    NA    NA
4     192   22.49376 17166.67 27177.04   450    39     NA     NA      NA   NA   NA    NA    NA
```

Because they are alternative and have fewer columns we can code it easily

```
Data=read.csv("mydata.csv")
firstData=Data[!is.na(Data$naux),]
secondData=Data[is.na(Data$naux),]
firstData$hoursw=secondData$tsales
firstData$hourspw=secondData$sales
firstData$inv1=secondData$margin
firstData$inv2=secondData$nown
firstData$ssize=secondData$nfull
firstData$start=secondData$npart
Data=firstData
```

Data is split into 2. The Odd rows and even rows. The odd rows are then replaced with the correct values provided in the even roes Data.
Hope this helps you!

The final output is

```
> firstData
   tsales    sales margin nown nfull npart   naux hoursw  hourspw     inv1     inv2 ssize start
1  750000 4411.765     41    1     1     1 1.5357     76 16.75596 17166.67 27177.04   170    41
3 1926395 4280.878     39    2     2     3 1.5357    192 22.49376 17166.67 27177.04   450    39

> secondData
  tsales    sales   margin     nown nfull npart naux hoursw hourspw inv1 inv2 ssize start
2     76 16.75596 17166.67 27177.04   170    41   NA     NA      NA   NA   NA    NA    NA
4    192 22.49376 17166.67 27177.04   450    39   NA     NA      NA   NA   NA    NA    NA

> Data
   tsales    sales margin nown nfull npart   naux hoursw  hourspw     inv1     inv2 ssize start
1  750000 4411.765     41    1     1     1 1.5357     76 16.75596 17166.67 27177.04   170    41
3 1926395 4280.878     39    2     2     3 1.5357    192 22.49376 17166.67 27177.04   450    39
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a `data.table` solution (I have copied your example into the file `dfTest.txt`). See comments for explanation:

```
library(data.table)
#fill=TRUE fills empty cols due to irregular structure with NAs
dt=fread("dfTest.txt",header = TRUE,sep=" ",fill=TRUE)
#cols to fix
selCols=c("hoursw","hourspw","inv1","inv2","ssize","start")
#cols from which to read
otherCols=colnames(dt)[seq_along(selCols)]
#fill missing cols from leading rows and select every 2nd row afterwards
dt[,c(selCols):=shift(.SD,n=1L,type="lead"),
    .SDcols=otherCols][seq(1,nrow(dt),2),]
```